# How is the WESTAR-34 blaster pistol (used by Jango Fett) powered?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, blasters

Jango Fett is armed with twin [WESTAR-34 blaster](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/WESTAR-34_blaster_pistol) pistols:

[image: WESTAR-34 blaster pistols (http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/1/15/Jango_Fett_blasters.png/revision/latest?cb=20161003043317)]

These weapons are quite small and I don't see any place to insert a power source.

Other weapons *do* require a power source. For example, Wookieepedia cites the canon reference book [*Ultimate Star Wars*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars) when it describes the capacity of the [E-11 blaster rifle](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/E-11_blaster_rifle):

> Its standard issue power cells carried energy for 100 shots however the rifle could also be loaded with plasma cartridges that could last for more than 500 shots.

Indeed there seems to be plenty of room on the E-11 to place a power cell or plasma cartridge:

[image: E-11 blaster rifle (http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/2/20/E-11_blaster_rifle_DICE.png/revision/latest?cb=20151106030234)]

(I believe the power cell is the near-white, square protrusion from the middle of the E-11 shown above.)

**Where is the power source for the WESTAR-34 blaster pistol? Does it acquire power some other way? How many shots can be fired before reloading?**

Comment: Do you consider the *Attack of the Clones* visual dictionary a good source?

Comment: @JasonBaker I prefer a canon source but I would upvote an answer which used that source. (Accepting an answer which uses that source would depend on whether or not there's a canon answer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [*Star Wars:* Attack of the Clones: *The Visual Dictionary*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Attack_of_the_Clones_The_Visual_Dictionary), a DK reference book published in 2002, the WESTAR-34 blasters have a power cell just above the grip:

[image]

Since this book was published long before the Great Disneyfication, I'm not confident that it can be considered a canon source. However, it seems unlikely that this is the kind of information that Disney would have changed.

Having looked through both [*Ultimate Star Wars*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars), the fully-canon DK reference book, and the *Attack of the Clones* novelizations, I can find no other relevant information.

Comment: Good find! I guess you have to slide it out the back to reload?

Comment: @Null That would be my assumption. I suppose it might be a break-action, but it's hard to tell from the picture

Comment: I checked Ultimate Star Wars, and it is not there.

Comment: Perhaps the back *is* the load; similar to the PPG on _Babylon 5_.